What is the difference between authorization claims and request parameters in ASP.NET?
What is the difference between using an authorization claim or role, and using the parameter of a, let's say, GET request?
For example, I want a user to access only his own data.
I can have a controller with two GET method - first using the parameter:
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataDTO>>> GetData(long userId)
{
    return _context.Data.Select(data => CreateDataDTO(data)).ToListAsync();
}

And according to this answer using the claim:
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataDTO>>> GetData()
{
    //[...]
    var user = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var userId = user.FindFirstValue("UserId");

    return _context.Data.Select(data => CreateDataDTO(data)).ToListAsync();
}

I might answer this myself by asking: is the only difference, that the one (claim) is getting encoded into a JWT Token, while the other (param) is readable by anyone observing the traffic?

If you allow the caller to pass in the userId as a parameter, an attacker could just try all sorts of different userId values and see what data they get back. When you require the user to log in and prove their identity and track that internally, you have a much "tighter" control over what data you're returning to the caller - they can't just request the data for other users, if they want to ...

It matters, if you want to get and use currently logged in user, better to use claims, parameter can be any value, and can be exploited. Also this will help you with HTTP return codes - 401, 403, etc. With custom logic with userId you have to sort of reinvent the wheel.

@marc_s but what stops the attacker of changing the userId within the claim? Isn't that also just part of the http-request-header?

The claims are typically only on the server - out of reach of an attacker. Typically, you have to authenticate - and the result of that authentication is a set of claims, on the server, which cannot be easily manipulated from the outside

Oh ok...I'm not quite familiar with the technical details. For some reason I always thought they are sent with the http-request (encoded as jwt) and the server would decode it and get the claims out of there....And to make that secure one would sign the request.
